# Setting up a home network to support server applications

Tags: 14.04, networking, home-directory, ldap, nis

I'm trying to setup a home network using Linux (14.04) and would like to know what the process is called where you have a client machine (or several) connected to a server using the programs from the server instead of the client. Like in schools and enterprises.

I have no idea what this process is called so I cannot Google it.

I have tried some methods like using LDAP & NIS, But they crash my client machine.

Could someone tell me what the name of this system is?

Comment: this doesn't work? http://michaelminn.com/linux/home_network/

Comment: Not really knowing what I was doing, I set mine up to mount samba shares using cifs at boot.  It works, but if I was doing it again, I'd use nfs, as suggested in the answer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/491808/cifs-vfs-error-messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setup you are describing is often referred to as a [thin client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client) configuration. You may find the [Linux Terminal Server Project (LSTP)](http://www.ltsp.org/) a good place to start.

Answer (score -1):

It may be that you are thinking of multi-tiered architecture. This would have a client like a browser, a web server like Apache, a database like SQL, etc.

To set that up at home, look for LAMP (Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP) and you'll find a lot of information including tutorials on setup, etc.